# how to re-enable anonymous login in openldap

Tags: openldap, ldapconnection, slapd

I have recently installed openldap 2.4.42 and disabled anonymous login using the following content in ldif file.

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc

I can even see **access to dn.base="" by * read** in slapd.conf file
Now, I have a application(wordpress blog) which is trying to connect to LDAP server using anonymous login and failing because of that reason. I tried few options but none of them are working. Can someone help me out on how to re-enable the LDAP anonymous login.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of configuration are you using ? slapd.conf or slapd.d/ folder ? You cannot use both at the same time.
Drop added olcDisallows & olcRequires configuration if you use slapd.d/ folder configuration.
Or
delete countrepart settings from slapd.conf file (disallow & require) if you use slapd.conf configuration file.

To delete what you said you added to activate this behavior, ie with an LDIF file for example:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon
-
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
-
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

You should also verify that targeted anonymous access is allowed by database ACLs (**olcAccess** parameter)

Comment: Thanks Abdelhamid MEDDEB I am using slapd.d folder for configuration. But, I still not sure how to drop olcDisallows and olcRequires configurations. Can you please suggest me how to perform that.

Comment: I modified the answer according your comment. Hope this help.